# IDA Pro Reset All Stack Pointers to Default

Tags: ida, decompilation, hexrays

Is there a way letting IDA scan all the database and reset all stack pointers values to it's default state that were previously modified? i.e like it was when I first started the analyzing the binary?

I'm asking because I used to change the stack pointers for some functions I couldn't read due to having `negative sp value` and I didn't know that it's going to affect all it's caller functions. So I would like to reset all stack pointers in all the database(Using IDA Pro 7.0).